# Reuse and pass dynamic object (CurrentPage) to Partial View MVC Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, umbraco, partial-views, reusability

I'm somewhat (6 months) new to MVC, and I like to use as little as code as possible, especially when it comes to reusable code, etc. I'm using Umbraco v7.2, and I have (3) tabs, all which use the same data type (custom grid v7).

The grid has (4) fields. Basically all (3) sections on my page are the same w/ the exception for the header and the object that is called (the dynamic object is what has the properties in them for the tab, which as I stated earlier, are the same).

How can I call a partial view and reuse the same code? The "foreach" is where I need to have this partial view called, as you can see it uses the same exact code w/ the exception of the object being iterated.

The "CurrentPage.XXXX" is what I need to pass, and I can have the same iterator

```
@foreach(var XXXX in CurrentPage.XXXX)   <---- partial view
```

View:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}

    <article class="accordion-wrapper">
        <div class="accordion-container accordion-contact">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mont-bold accordion">Leadership Team</a>
            @foreach (var leadership in CurrentPage.leadershipTeam)
            {
                <section class="clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>@leadership.contactName</li>
                            <li>@leadership.contactTitle</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <aside class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>@leadership.contactPhone</li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="mailto:@leadership.contactEmail">@leadership.contactEmail</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                </section>
            }
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="accordion-wrapper">
        <div class="accordion-container accordion-contact">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mont-bold accordion">The Lenders One Team</a>
            @foreach (var lenders in CurrentPage.lendersTeam)
            {
                <section class="clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>@lenders.contactName</li>
                            <li>@lenders.contactTitle</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <aside class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>@lenders.contactPhone</li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="mailto:@lenders.contactEmail">@lenders.contactEmail</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                </section>
            }
        </div>
    </article>

    .... another one here but omitted for brevity
```

And turn it into:

```
    <article class="accordion-wrapper">
        <div class="accordion-container accordion-contact">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mont-bold accordion">Leadership Team</a>
            @Html.Partial( ?????? )
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="accordion-wrapper">
        <div class="accordion-container accordion-contact">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mont-bold accordion">The Lenders One Team</a>
            @Html.Partial( ?????? )
        </div>
    </article>
```

Partial ???

```
            @foreach (var contact in ??????)
            {
                <section class="clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>@contact.contactName</li>
                            <li>@contact.contactTitle</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <aside class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>@contact.contactPhone</li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="mailto:@contact.contactEmail">@contact.contactEmail</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                </section>
            }
```

Appreciate it ;)

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I've used partial views before in Umbraco. The issue above is I have (3) different objects ([grids in u7](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/u7-grid-data-type)). How the grid works in Umbraco is you create a new data type, and define certain fields in that data type (textbox, media picker, etc). You can then add properties to document types (in this case I used the custom grid I created). Once a page is created, based off a document type, properties are inherited.

For the contact page, I needed (3) separate grids. However each grid has different data in them. Therefore this is (3) different JSON objects, which I iterate over. In the above code, the (3) JSON objects are:

1. leadershipTeam
2. lendersTeam
3. avisoryBoard (the one omitted for
       brevity)

How can I pass (CurrentPage.JSONobjectHere) to the partial view, **using only ONE partial view for all THREE sections**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did something similar to this once.

Call your partial like this:

```
@Html.Partial("YourPartialName", (object)CurrentPage.lendersTeam)
```

And then use a dynamic as a model in your partial:

```
@model dynamic
@foreach (var contact in Model)
            {
                <section class="clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>@contact.contactName</li>
                            <li>@contact.contactTitle</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <aside class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>@contact.contactPhone</li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="mailto:@contact.contactEmail">@contact.contactEmail</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                </section>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not too difficult.  In the call to the partial, just use the **name** of the partial.  This is the filename of the partial without the extention.  The current "Model" will also be available in your partial without you have to pass something to the partial.

```
<article class="accordion-wrapper">
    <div class="accordion-container accordion-contact">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mont-bold accordion">Leadership Team</a>
        @Html.Partial("NameOfThePartialWithoutExtention")
    </div>
</article>
```

If you inherit from [UmbracoTemplatePage or the UmbracoViewPage](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/52597-What-is-the-difference-between-UmbracoViewPage-and-UmbracoTemplatePage), then you can use the model as if you were in the View itself.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@foreach (var contact in CurrentPage.Children)
{
    <section class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <ul>
                <li>@contact.contactName</li>
                <li>@contact.contactTitle</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
     </section>
 }
```

Comment: This did not have the expected outcome, as no data was displayed. I've updated my question (EDIT) w/ more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Morten OC. Thumbs up. I was using NestedContent and calling Partial view to render IPublishedContent, but also wanted access to CurrentPage.

Simple cast to object first worked. To elaborate, here's some extra code in case someone needs the same -

```
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/MyPartial.cshtml", 
                        item, //for me this is an IPublishedContent
                        new ViewDataDictionary { { "CurrentPage", (object)CurrentPage } });
```

Then in my Partial, shortened for brevity -

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IPublishedContent>
@{
    dynamic CurrentPage = ViewBag.CurrentPage;
}

<p>@CurrentPage.Name</p>
```

So my Model is IPublishedContent (since I was iterating through nested contents)

And then in ViewBag you'll have a reference to CurrentPage. I named it CurrentPage just so I could continue using CurrentPage as we typically do in Umbraco.

Cheers Morten H5YR